# Hop SSH servers with same key and escalate to root then query mysql and export results

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, root

Ideally, I would like to use a some sort of GUI to perform MySQL queries and be able to export results to the host computer.

I need my host to ssh into a jump server, then ssh to another server, housing the mysql service. From there I need to switch to root, and then I will be able to query.

Originally I thought I could tunnel to the first box, then use mysql workbench's options to ssh into the last box and perform queries. However I would need to be able to change to root first, but i don't see a way to do that.

My situation as follows:

```
Host - > jump_server -> dest_server -> "sudo su -" -> mysql queries
```

If there is no convenient GUI way to do this, what would be the best one liner, to run a query from the host and save results to the host.

Comment: You (ordinarily) don't need to escalate to root to run a mysql query.

Comment: This is correct. However, in this scenario, I do.

Comment: Is adding the user to `/etc/sudoers` with `NOPASSWD` for `/usr/bin/mysql` an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Quite the puzzle.

Comment: Well, I guess you could throw security out the window and have a script on the mysql server which is `echo $LOOK_AT_MY_PASSWORD_WITH_PS | sudo -S -i`